# Class names, 'test', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

Tags: java, cmd

Хочу запустить код java через cmd, и он выдает ошибку. Что делать? На название не обращайте внимание.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class piska {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Привет мир!");
    }
}
```

Comment: javac [fileName].java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063266/javac-error-class-names-are-only-accepted-if-annotation-processing-is-explicitl

Answer (score 0):

Я понял. Чтобы скомпилировать нужно писать javac, а чтобы запустить нужно писать java.